How to remove modal div element after navigation in React?
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

const LoginPage = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      const url = "http://localhost:8000/api/login";
      const response = await axios.post(url, {
        email: email,
        password: password,
      });
      console.log(response.data);
      Cookies.set("token", response.data.token);
      navigate("/home");
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
        setErrors(error.response.data.errors);
      }
    }
  };

  const handleInputClick = () => {
    setErrors({});
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="modal fade"
      id="loginModal"
      aria-labelledby="loginModalLabel"
      aria-hidden="true"
    >
      <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-fullscreen-md-down">
        <div className="modal-content">
          <div className="modal-header">
            <h5 className="modal-title" id="loginModalLabel">
              Авторизация
            </h5>
            <button
              type="button"
              class="btn-close"
              data-bs-dismiss="modal"
              aria-label="Close"
            ></button>
          </div>
          <div className="modal-body">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <div className="form-group mb-3 text-start">
                <label className="mb-1">Email</label>
                <input
                  type="email"
                  onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                  onClick={handleInputClick}
                  value={email}
                  className={`form-control ${errors.email ? "is-invalid" : ""}`}
                  placeholder="Введите ваш адрес электронной почты"
                />
                {errors.email && (
                  <div className="invalid-feedback">{errors.email[0]}</div>
                )}
              </div>
              <div className="form-group mb-3 text-start">
                <label className="mb-1">Пароль</label>
                <input
                  type="password"
                  onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                  onClick={handleInputClick}
                  value={password}
                  className={`form-control ${errors.email ? "is-invalid" : ""}`}
                  placeholder="Введите ваш пароль"
                />
                {errors.email && (
                  <div className="invalid-feedback">{errors.email[0]}</div>
                )}
              </div>
              <div className="container-fluid p-0 d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-3">
                <div className="form-check text-start me-auto">
                  <input type="checkbox" className="form-check-input"></input>
                  <label className="form-check-label">Запомнить меня</label>
                </div>
                <p className="m-0">
                  <a class="link-opacity-75-hover" href="#">
                    Забыли пароль?
                  </a>
                </p>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary d-flex ms-auto">
                Войти
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LoginPage;

I have a React component LoginPage, where modal window pops up when user clicks a button on the other page. The problem is that after successfully logging in user navigates to the /home page and there is a div element <div class="modal-backdrop fade show"></div> on fullscreen.
I need to remove this element. How can I do this?

I am new to React and tried different ways fixing this by asking ChatGPT

I dont see element modal-backdrop in the code

Is the loginPage component present on every page?
If it's not used to log the user out, you can check if the token is present before rendering the component.
Something like
{!checkToken() && (
   <LoginPage />
)}

But it's hard to give you a concrete answer without knowing the structure of the project.
But a more appropiate way to do it, is checking in the navigation if the token is present and valid and seperate the navigation stacks depending on the users login status.
    isSignedIn ? (
  <>
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
  </>
) : (
  <>
    <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUpScreen} />
  </>
);

Example above is from react documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/
